# Structural Architecture code in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I am new to vhdl and I am trying to compile a code using structural model. I have a simple example shown below:

```
ENTITY equiv IS
    PORT (a, b : IN BIT; 
          c    : OUT BIT);
END equiv;

ARCHITECTURE structure OF equiv IS

    SIGNAL tmp : BIT;

    COMPONENT xor2
        PORT (x, y : IN BIT; z : OUT BIT);
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT inv 
        PORT (x : IN BIT; z : OUT BIT); 
    END COMPONENT;

BEGIN

    u0: xor2 PORT MAP (a, b, tmp);
    u1: inv PORT MAP (tmp, c);

END structure;
```

When I try to compile this code, I keep receiving an error which says:

"Undefined objects in selected scope"

I am also confused as to how the code will determine xor2 is xor? What is the internal working of this code? I tried searching, but I could not find anything. I wan't to get my basics right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate 2 components here (xor2 and inv2).  However the compiler doesn't know anything about them, so it says undefined objects.  Your question is spot-on, you need to define the internal working of this code.

You need to create your own file called xor2.vhd and define the entity/architecture for it.  You already know what it SHOULD look like based on your component definition:
    COMPONENT xor2 PORT (x, y : IN BIT; z : OUT BIT); END COMPONENT;

x and y are inputs of type bit, z is an output of type bit.  So write the inner-workings, then compile those first, then compile this all into the same library and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes more sense now!